# Issue queuing HTML5 FileReader()s to be read later

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, filereader

I'm currently working on a Google Chrome app that will allow users to open image files for viewing.

What I found was that it was far too hurtful to performance to read many files concurrently, so I decided to make a queue, and a limit as to how many files can be read concurrently.

However, the issue I am facing is with my file reading function, **readFile(*file*)**.

**At one point, files stop being read, and I am left with 3 readers, and all the remaining files still in the queue. This is the result:**[image: Screenshot of JSFiddle]

I have rewritten and omitted some parts of the JavaScript and CSS to make it web browser ready, and [here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/few270un/).

Here is the function in its entirety, along with some of the variables associated within the function:

```
var data = [], readers = [];

function readFile(file){
  if(readers.length >= 4){
    //if there are already 4 files being read concurrently
    queue.push(file);
  }else{
    //Note: remove last reader, first from queue
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = '<img/>Loading...';
    fileList.appendChild(item);

    readers.push(new FileReader());
    var currentReader = readers[readers.length-1]; //get the last reader

    currentReader.addEventListener('error',function(){

    });

    currentReader.addEventListener('load',function(event){
      var result = this.result||event.target.result;
      var img = item.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

      var tmp = new Image();
      tmp.src = result;

        data.push({
          "file":file,
          "name":file.name,
          "ext":file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf(".")),
          "item":item,
          "img":result,
          "thumb":img
        });

      tmp.addEventListener('load',function(){
        canvas2.width = canvas2.height = thumbnailDimension;
        ctx2.drawImage(this,0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
        img.src = canvas2.toDataURL('image/webp','.1');
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(queue.length){
            readFile(queue[0]);
            queue.splice(0,1);
          }

          readers.splice(readers.length-1,1);
        },1000);
      });

    });

    currentReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

For my app, I want to read the files, resize a canvas, and draw the images onto it to make thumbnails for a side panel. For that reason, the temporary image, **img**, must be loaded before the next file can be read (to prevent things from being added to the queue twice). As you can see, I set a **one second delay**, but I am still having an issue.

Thank you all for your helpful answers in advance. If you would like to reproduce the problem I am having for yourself, just select a LOT of image files. I chose 168 JPG files (each around 500-600k).

**Update: 1/7/2015 11:39am EST:** I did some inspecting and found that the `tmp` would stop firing it's onload event. Maybe it's bad to have one event listener inside of another? If so, how could I achieve getting the thumbnails to load at a proper time?

Answer (score 0):

@RickyAYoder, seems there is an error on the page. Run debugger on your browser (Chrome is the best!) to see if there are any other errors. I see launchData is not defined in your code:

```
function onLaunch(){
  if(!(launchData && launchData.items && launchData.items[0])) return;

  for(var x = 0; x < launchData.items.length; x++){
    //iterate through files passed to app
    launchData.items[x].entry.file(function(file){

  });
 }

 Draw();
}
onLaunch();
```

can you check to see if it is defined somewhere??

Comment: Oops. Ignore that. launchData is for the Chrome app only.

Comment: ok. are there any other errors on the page that you can see in the debugger?? also, you have this line of code which you never remove:  item.innerHTML = '<img/>Loading...'; after file is uploaded. When is that supposed to be removed? and I see all files uploaded on the left <div>, but nothing is displayed on the <main div>. Maybe you are missing some code on the fiddle??

Comment: The innerHTML setting is to populate each div on the left panel with the appropriate data. The empty image from that has it's source set via the current file reader's onload event.